# Reference materials for learning Google API V3 with PHP and MySQL (tracking)

Tags: google-maps, php, mysql, google-maps-api

I am new to this Google API. Now i wanted to learn Google API with PHP and MySQL.

Actually i wanted to create an application  that will track x,y coordinates coordinates on real time bases for android mobile. There will be many Android mobiles which will send data on real time bases and using php and mySQL i wanted to display it on Google map and refresh display and data after certain time interval.

So with respect to this tracking system part can any one suggest me any references material and web site.

Comment: I'd also be interested in a link or a short step-by-step to implement something like this. I imagine the MySQL Db tables might get a bit large after recording the coordinates for a good amount of time. What kind of Refresh rate are you look at? <30 seconds?

Comment: Did you even try googling it? Top result https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3 You also need to start accepting answers to some of your questions or people will not help you

Comment: Refresh rate will have a drop-down list so user can select as per requirement from 1second to 5mins! Is it possible?

Comment: Yes i tried googling but no as useful result was found. Which also really confused me.

Comment: Read the Terms first  (10c iii) Tracking https://developers.google.com/maps/terms 'you must not: enterprise dispatch, fleet management, business asset tracking or similar applications...

Comment: Thanks for giving me this link for reading first. But if its a college or study level project then can i go with google? As i am creating my academic project. or else can you please suggest me another map? if this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

I did a work project like what you described with no experience in the Google Maps API, PHP or mySQL.  I worked from this document from Google's developer's resources: [From info window to Database.](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3)

For my project:

- A user clicks on the map to drop a point
- An info window pops up with an html form
- The Lat and Long auto fill based on the location of the dropped point (auto-update if the user drags the point to a new location)
- The user fills out the form, which is validated client side with jQuery
- On form submit (jQuery ajax) the info is sent to a php processing page (php POST), the info window changes to 'Thank you for submitting your sighting'
- Entry is added to mySQL from php page with INSERT statement

Make sure you do validation on your php processing page too to avoid SQL injection.